# Parallel Evaluation

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization

I want to speed-up the following program for obtaining Poincare Sections

```
 sol[r0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] :=NDSolve[{r'[t] == Fr/Ft, z'[t] == Fz/Ft, 
 r[0] == r0, z[0] == z0}, {r,z}, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> "Automatic"];

 p[t_] := Evaluate[{r[t], z[t]} /. sol[#, 0] & /@ Range[0.6, 3.8, 0.1]];


 ptab = Table[ListPlot[Table[Table[p[i][[j]][[1]], {i, k, tmax-k, 2 Pi}], 
 {j, 1, Length[p[i]]}], PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.0033]}}, ImageSize 
 -> 290, PlotLabel -> {"phi=", k}], {k, 0, 3 Pi/4, Pi/4}]
```

where $Fr,\, Fz,\, Ft $ are given by analytic expressions. I use the
     ParallelEvaluate
command, but it doesn't work!

What can I do for parallel computation or in general for a faster algorithm?

Also how can I do the same procedure for $Fr,\, Fz,\, Ft$ given by numerical data and not by analytic expressions?

Comment: Curious if you have seen the [Poincaré Sections](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PoincareSections.html) featured example. You can find this by searching for "Poincare Sections" in the help.

Comment: @Edmund, I've seen that. My problem is not how to take the Poincare section. The problem is that whenever $F_r$, $F_z$, $F_t$ are complicated functions the calculation takes hours. I need a speed boost...

Comment: To obtain meaningful answers, please provide sample expressions for `Fr`, `Fz`, and `Ft`, preferably simple ones.

Comment: `ParallelEvaluate` probably does not do what you expect, it will evaluate the same expression on all parallel kernels, which of course will not achieve any speedup but calculate the same result on every kernel. To see speedup you should use `ParallelTable` instead of `Table`, but I would only try to parallelize the outermost `Table`. You probably will also need to play with the `Method` option to really see a speedup, but what is the best setting for that depends a lot on how complicated your calculations really are...